# React ES6 onClick change other components

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a table that has a normal row and then two rows after it that are hidden until the plus icon is clicked on. When the icon is clicked it should change to a minus and the hidden rows should change CSS classes. Also should work in reverse.

```
import React from 'react';

class HiddenRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr className="hidden-row">
        <td>Stuff</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class NormalRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('here');
    // Expand rows if hidden change icon to fa-minus-circle
    // Hide rows if not and change icon to fa-plus-circle
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td><i className="fa fa-plus-circle" onClick={this.handleClick}></i> Hello</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class ParentDiv extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <NormalRow />
            <HiddenRow />
            <HiddenRow />
            <NormalRow />
            <HiddenRow />
            <HiddenRow />
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:** The table will have multiple sets of Normal rows and Hidden rows. Clicking on the icon in the normal row should toggle only the two immediate hidden rows. I was using JQuery to do this when I was using Angular but switched to React. I've been playing around w/ JQuery with React as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to communicate between the NormalRow Component and the two HiddenRow Components. In your code the best way is to manage it in the ParentDiv, as follows:

```
class ParentDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      displayHiddenRows: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <NormalRow onClick={this.handlePlusClicked.bind(this)} />
            <HiddenRow show={this.state.displayHiddenRows} />
            <HiddenRow show={this.state.displayHiddenRows} />
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handlePlusClicked() {
    this.setState = {
      displayHiddenRows: true
    }
  }
}
```

In the hidden rows add a condition for the className by the show prop.
In the normal row replace the handleClick with this.props.onClick function.

Comment: This might simply open them but not sure it will hide them on a second click. Think the handle should be `this.setState = { displayHiddenRows: !this.state.displayHiddenRows }`

Comment: Also my example will have multiple sets of Normal/Hidden rows.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `NormalRow` and a couple of `HiddenRow`s that follow are a part of the same *control*. That said, I would consider creating a separate React component for them that would encapsulate the click event handling as well as the view/hide logic of the underlying "normal" and "hidden" rows. All of this could be achieved in pure React (so no jQuery required).

The mark-up generated by that new, higher level component would be either a single or three table rows, depending on its state. But since the `render` method cannot return multiple elements, you'd need to use a wrapper and my preference would be `<tbody>` (as opposed to e.g. `<div>` that tends to be misused in such scenarios). To my best knowledge you can have as many `<tbody>` tags in a table as you want so this would be a *valid* choice.

With this new component (let's call it `ActiveRow`) your `ParentDiv` component would look like this:

```
class ParentDiv extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <ActiveRow />
          <ActiveRow />
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice I've removed the `<tbody>` wrapper here as it's now returned by `ActiveRow`.